# Image compression for Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook

This may be a non-issue but I am trying to figure out where the Facebook album photo image compression happens, before or after upload.  I am sending a UIimage to a Facebook album that ends up being around 43 kb jpeg at 640X480 in Facebook, similar to my other uploaded photos from other sources.  If I attach the same UIImage to a email it is a 461 kb jpeg at 640x480.

The Facebook upload is taking a while and I would like to speed it up so I have 2 questions.

1. Where does the compression occur, on Facebook server or on my device in the facebook SDK?
2. If it is happening on the server how do I compress a UIImage on my device before upload without resizing (resample to 100X80 or something) like you are allowed to do with a jpeg.  I have tried to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation but the Facebook SDK gives me a error if it is sent NSData instead of a UIImage.

Comment: were you able to determine if Facebook SDK compresses image on device?

Comment: At the time I wrote this I determined that the Facebook SDK did not compress images before uploading even though Facebook did on the server.  I code I changed produced ruffly the same quality as the final photo on Facebook would if uploaded with original SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more digging I replaced this section of code:

```
       NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage*)dataParam);
    [self utfAppendBody:body
                   data:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", key]];
    [self utfAppendBody:body
                   data:[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"]];
```

in FBRequest.m with this section of code:

```
      NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((UIImage*)dataParam, 1);
      [self utfAppendBody:body
                     data:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", key]];
      [self utfAppendBody:body
                     data:[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"]];
```

and found it loads in about half the time.  Guess I will make a post  on git